# Seconds counter in the if statement

Tags: swift

I, I tried using `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in` but it do not works how I would like to. Here is me idea:

```
If certatin rotation is true {

start timer;
if timer = 2seconds{
perform some action
}
if timer = 3 seconds{
perform another action
}


}else stop timer
```

My CODE:

```
 //===============================================FIRTS
                    if Counter == 1 {
                    if self.Bottle.zRotation < -0.94 && self.Bottle.zPosition > -0.98 {

                        self.WaterDrop.alpha = 1

                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
                            self.GlassWater1.alpha = 0.5
                            self.BottleWater6.alpha = 0.0
                            self.WaterDrop.setScale(CGFloat(1.2))
                            })
                        Counter = 2
                        print(Counter)
                        }else {
                        self.WaterDrop.alpha = 0.0
                        self.WaterDrop.setScale(CGFloat(1.0))
                        Counter = 1
                        // print(Counter)
                    }
                    }
                    //===============================================SECOND
                    if Counter == 2 {
                        if self.Bottle.zRotation < -0.94 && self.Bottle.zPosition > -0.98 {

                            self.WaterDrop.alpha = 1

                            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
                                self.GlassWater2.alpha = 0.5
                                self.BottleWater5.alpha = 0.0
                                self.WaterDrop.setScale(CGFloat(1.4))
                                })
                            Counter = 3
                            // print(Counter)
                        }else {
                            self.WaterDrop.alpha = 0.0
                            self.WaterDrop.setScale(CGFloat(1.0))
                            Counter = 1
                           //  print(Counter)
                        }
                    }
                    //===============================================Third
                    if Counter == 3 {
                        if self.Bottle.zRotation < -0.94 && self.Bottle.zPosition > -0.98 {

                            self.WaterDrop.alpha = 1

                            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
                                self.GlassWater3.alpha = 0.5
                                self.BottleWater4.alpha = 0.0
                                self.WaterDrop.setScale(CGFloat(1.4))
                            })
                            Counter = 4
                            // print(Counter)
                        }else {
                            self.WaterDrop.alpha = 0.0
                            self.WaterDrop.setScale(CGFloat(1.0))
                            Counter = 1
                            // print(Counter)
                        }
                    }


                  //  print("tilred in z")
                }
```

Comment: You must install the newly created Timer on a `RunLoop`,    `RunLoop.current.add(putYourTimerHere, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)`

Comment: @user9335240 No, you must not. The API ***scheduled**Timer(* adds the timer implicitly to the runloop.

Comment: @vadian Sorry, and thanks for clarification

Comment: So it should looks like this?

`If If certatin rotation is true {
RunLoop.current.add(Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in CODE_HERE})

RunLoop.current.add(Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in Another_Code_Here})

}`

?

Comment: `it do not works how I would like to` - please add the Swift code instead of the pseudocode, it's hard for us to tell what's wrong without the actual code.

Comment: @user9335240 Now that you put some Swift code in, it looks like you're trying to animate stuff. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Take a variable `time` in your viewController:

```
var time = 0
```

Then do this :

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in

     time = time.advanced(by: 1)
     if time == 2 {
          //Perform something at 2 seconds
     }else if time == 3 {
          //Perform something at 3 seconds
     }else {
          //Stop Timer
          timer.invalidate()
     }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You beat me to it! (You posted your answer while I was composing mine.)

Comment: Your code with addidtional ifs in if time == 2 works perfect. Thank You!

Comment: @PawełCzech Happy Coding!!

Answer (score -1):

It isn't clear what you mean by "if timer = 2 seconds".

Is this code in a function that runs repeatedly, or code that runs inside the block for a timer?

The code might look something like this

```
//Create an instance variable to track how many times the timer has fired.
var count: Int = 0


count = 0 //Reset the count so we start at 0 every time we trigger a timer.
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0 repeats: true block) { timer in
  self.count += 1
  if count == 2 {
    //your action code
  } else if count == 3 {
    //your other action code
  } else if count >= 4 {
    timer.invalidate()
  }
```

}